# What module loader ember.js is using?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am wondering what module loader ember.js is using?

I check the docs in ember-cli, it mentioned the compiled module is AMD(RequireJS). But what is the module loader library? Like angular is using webpack.

Answer (score 1):

It's [`loader.js`](https://github.com/ember-cli/loader.js). It's a minimal loader for ember.